# Could not load System.Web.Extension when add reference to net 4.x from net core 3.1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a project in net core 3.1 and I add reference that written in net 4.x. When I call method of referenced dll which calling http request error occured that could not load file or assembly 'system.web.extensions, version=4.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=31bf3856ad364e35'. the system cannot find the file specified.' How can I solve it?

Comment: You should make sure you have installed the .net framework 4.0 in your application server.

Comment: using visual studio I can create and run a program with .net framework 4.0

Comment: Referencing .net framework library from a .net core application isn't recommended and can produce unpredictable results. When you do the reference, the .net framework library is treated as a .net standard library and all the types in there will be type forwarded to .net core runtime types. That, if the type is not supported in .net core, the type breaks, if the type's behavior has been changed in .net core, the type works as per .net core runtime.